# Angularjs ngAnimate not being injected

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

Why is ngAnimate not being "injected" into the application?

This is my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script)
<script type="text/javascript">

var myApp = angular.module("application", ["ngAnimate"]);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', 
        ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {
    ...
}
```

Seems pretty simple code but I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=application&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.26%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapplication%0AC%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0AZc%2Fb.module%2Fb%5Be%5D%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1%0AZc%2Fb.module%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1%0Agc%2Fe%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A267%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Agc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309%0Afc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170%0Afc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387%0AXc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A215%3A30%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.10.2%2Fjquery.min.js%3A4%3A26031%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fp.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.10.2%2Fjquery.min.js%3A4%3A26840%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.10.2%2Fjquery.min.js%3A4%3A3303%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.10.2%2Fjquery.min.js%3A4%3A715%0A


...gify(arguments[c]):arguments[c]);return Error(a)}}function Pa(b){if(null==b||Ga(...
```

Have searched endlessly on Google and SO for answer but none there was forthcoming...

Comment: Have you possibility to switch to angular 1.3.x and test it? I remember having same issue and somehow it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script)
```

must be

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

The bracket `)` is wrong.